# Identifying a remote PC behind a router for Windows Remote Desktop Connection

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

WindowsRemote Desktop Connection wants the IP or name of the remote computer to connect to. But suppose the remote computer is behind a router. The router has one WAN IP, say 192.45.63.98, which will be the same for all the computers connected off of that router, (when you google "my ip" from any of them) and then each computer connected off of the router will have a LAN IP, something like 10.0.0.6. So if I want to help the person connected to the 10.0.0.6 computer (and not the person connected at 10.0.0.9) what do I tell Remote Desktop Connection at my computer to reach them?

Thanks.

Comment: You want Super User for this question, not Stack Overflow. Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup something called port forwarding on your router. Assuming your are running your Windows Remote Desktop Server on port 3389 which is standard, you would setup a port forward to forward port 3389 to the internal IP address of the RDP server (the one starting 10.0.0.x)

Comment: Thanks, but that's waay too much work to set up a remote desktop access. Several people suggested Teamviewer instead of Microsoft RDC and after trying it it is indeed much easier.